# localhost/test/web_root/ is ok but localhost/test/web_root/index not found in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

i create zend structure following

```
   -test
     -application
       -controllers
       -modules
       -views
         -filters
         -helpers
         -scripts
           -index
           -user
     -library
       +zend //zend file or modules
     -web_root
       -css
       -img
       -js
       .htaccess
       index.php
```

code in ./test/web_root/

**.htaccess**

```
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule .* index.php
```

and **index.php** code is

```
     <?php
         error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
         ini_set('display_errors', true);
         date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

         $rootDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
         set_include_path($rootDir . '/library' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

         require_once 'Zend/Controller/Front.php';
         Zend_Controller_Front::run('../application/controllers');

    ?>
```

code in ./test/application/controllers

**IndexController.php** code is

```
        <?php
             require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action.php';

             class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
             {
                 public function indexAction()
                 {
                     $this->view->assign('title', 'Hello, World!');
                 $this->view->assign('wellcome','Wellcome to my site.');
                 $this->view->assign('webmaster','Wiwit');
                 }

              }
        ?>
```

and **UserController.php**

```
<?php
   require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action.php';

   class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
   {
     public function indexAction()
     {
       $this->view->assign('name', 'Wiwit');
       $this->view->assign('title', 'Hello');
     }

     public function nameAction()
     {
       $this->view->assign('name', 'Wiwit');
       $this->view->assign('title', 'User Name');  
     } 

  }
```

?>

code in ./test/application/views/scripts/index

**index.phtml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhmtl">
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
      <title><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>
        <?=$this->escape($this->wellcome);?>
       <p>&nbsp;</p>
       <?=$this->escape($this->webmaster);?>
   </body>
   </html>
```

code in ./test/application/views/scripts/user

**index.phtml**

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title><? echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></title>
   </head>

   <body>
     <h1><?=$this->escape($this->title);?>, <?=$this->escape($this->name);?></h1>
   </body>
   </html>
```

similar problem not found url

```
  localhost/test/web_root/user
```